# Run custom SQL when publish from Visual Studio to Azure website

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, azure

I am using entity framework code first with migrations and have been deploying from Visual Studio to an azure website just fine.

I now have added a few stored procedures and would like to deploy them at the same time as publishing.

I have SQL scripts to drop and create the stored procedures - and they are checked into source control.  So it would be good if these scripts could be run against the database automatically with every deployment.  These would have to be run after any database migration scripts have been automatically run as part of the deployment - since they could refer to the revised database schema.

Please could you advise how this can be done. Thanks.